# Traer los ultimos registros de cada disciplina en sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy buscando la manera de como traer las ultimas inscripciones por cada disciplina que el cliente se haya registrado. Formulé el siguiente script pero no me trae de todas las disciplinas. Por ejemplo, si existe de 4 disciplinas solo me trae de 2 registros ¿Alguien me podria echar un mano?

```
select p.CI,p.Nombre,p.ApellidoPaterno,
        p.ApellidoMaterno,c.Foto,co.NombreTipoInscripcion,
        d.NombreDiciplina,i.CodInscripcion,Convert(Varchar(10),di.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento, 
        Convert(Varchar(10),i.FechaInscripcion,103) AS FechaInscripcion,
        p.CodPersona,p.Telefono,
        p.Sexo,p.Peso,p.FechaNacimiento,
        c.Correo 
from Persona p 
inner join Cliente c on c.CodCliente=p.CodPersona 
inner join Inscripcion i on i.CodCliente=c.CodCliente 
inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodInscripcion=i.CodInscripcion 
inner join (select MAX(CodInscripcion )as CodInscripcion,
                    CodDiciplina 
            from DetalleInscripcion  
            group by CodDiciplina) ULTIMAINS on ULTIMAINS.CodDiciplina=di.CodDiciplina and i.CodInscripcion=ULTIMAINS.CodInscripcion 
inner join DiciplinaTipoInscripcion dc on dc.CodTipoInscripcion=di.CodTipoInscripcion and dc.CodDiciplina = di.CodDiciplina  
inner join Diciplina d on d.CodDiciplina=di.CodDiciplina 
inner join TipoInscripcion co on co.CodTipoInscripcion=di.CodTipoInscripcion 
where p.CI='9605006rr'
```

Esta es la BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: siempre ayuda darle algo de identacion al codigo para que sea legible

Comment: no entiendo, realizas un join a `DetalleInscripcion`, pero despues ademas defines una subconsulta nuevamente a `DetalleInscripcion` para aplicar un `group by`  y generar `ULTIMAINS` pero unes esto con diferentes campos, a una la realcionas usando solo `CodInscripcion` mientras que a la otra la realciones con `CodDiciplina` y `CodInscripcion ` si se trata de la misma tabla como puede relacionarse diferente, eso esta raro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma común de hacerlo es asignando un orden al resultado mediante `ROW_NUMBER()` para después mostrar sólo la fila 1 de cada grupo según el orden establecido. Para eso se puede usar una subconsulta o un CTE como en el siguiente ejemplo.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    select  p.CI,
            p.Nombre,
            p.ApellidoPaterno,
            p.ApellidoMaterno,
            c.Foto,
            co.NombreTipoInscripcion,
            d.NombreDiciplina,
            i.CodInscripcion,
            Convert(Varchar(10),di.FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento, 
            Convert(Varchar(10),i.FechaInscripcion,103) AS FechaInscripcion,
            p.CodPersona,
            p.Telefono,
            p.Sexo,p.Peso,p.FechaNacimiento,
            c.Correo,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY di.CodDiciplina ORDER BY i.FechaInscripcion DESC) AS rn
    from Persona p 
    inner join Cliente c on c.CodCliente=p.CodPersona 
    inner join Inscripcion i on i.CodCliente=c.CodCliente 
    inner join DetalleInscripcion di on di.CodInscripcion=i.CodInscripcion 
    inner join DiciplinaTipoInscripcion dc on dc.CodTipoInscripcion=di.CodTipoInscripcion and dc.CodDiciplina = di.CodDiciplina  
    inner join Diciplina d on d.CodDiciplina=di.CodDiciplina 
    inner join TipoInscripcion co on co.CodTipoInscripcion=di.CodTipoInscripcion 
    where p.CI='9605006rr'
)
SELECT  CI,
        Nombre,
        ApellidoPaterno,
        ApellidoMaterno,
        Foto,
        NombreTipoInscripcion,
        NombreDiciplina,
        CodInscripcion,
        Convert(Varchar(10),FechaVencimiento,103) AS FechaVencimiento, 
        Convert(Varchar(10),FechaInscripcion,103) AS FechaInscripcion,
        CodPersona,
        Telefono,
        Sexo,
        Peso,
        FechaNacimiento,
        Correo
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: muchas gracias desconocia de la funcion ROW_NUMBER()